# HTC One M7 Text messaging problems

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sms

I Have a HTC One M7 that had it's software updated 5/26/15. 
The only problem i'm facing is that **I can't read my text messages.**

I can open my text threads, but it won't show the actual text messages. I've tried restarting my phone, rebooting, deleting threads, and waiting as long as 30 minutes to see if the messages would appear. All of no use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache/data of the Messaging app in you Settings --> Apps-> All Apps --> Messaging ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using another messaging app instead if the default one like hangouts or Google messenger. 
You can change the settings for default messaging app in "more" in the settings app.